# How to strictly define a record in the return type

Tags: typescript

Given the following type:

```js
type Fn = () => Record<"A" | "B", boolean>;
```

I want to enforce the following typing:

```js
const fn: Fn = () => ({
  A: true,
  B: true,

  // @ts-expect-error C should throw an error
  C: false
})
```

I was wondering if there's a way I could enforce typescript to accept only the exact return type and no more than that.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgOxgXhgCgJQoHwwEpQDGA9gE4AmAPAEQCC1MAPjNQELUA0MARscQDZQAhgmwBuYMBIIAziBgAzBAC54SVJhzoA3sBgxaqkKQCuUDnpisjp85P0B6BzAACIGQFooAD2iEQXqSkZDAAwjAyABbEJvzkMCCRwQDuMCIwUEFklqGqCkL8MlDAAL4YQA)

Comment: Since TypeScript doesn't have "exact types" as requested in [ms/TS#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) and [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) doesn't kick in for (non-annotated) function return types, there's not much you can do to get this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it's impossible. The return type is covariance.

I checked typescript configs, there is no parameter to prevent return type covariance.

The only way I can find is declare the return value as its type before return.

```
type Ret = Record<"A" | "B", boolean>
type Fn = () => Ret;

const fn: Fn = () => {
  const ret: Ret = {
    A: true,
    B: true,
    C: false
  }
  return ret
}
```

Comment: Your edit rejects *everything*, though; `Exclude<string, K>` is going to be `string` (unless `K` is itself `string`) and so *all* keys are going to be `never`.  [Observe](https://tsplay.dev/mbGD3W).

Comment: @Observe Thank you, it's a stupid mistake. I have delete it.